# how to get index of sorted array elements

Tags: r

Say I have an array in R    : `c(10, 7, 4, 3, 8, 2)`
Upon sorting, this would be : `c(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10)`

What is the best way in R to return the indices for the sorted array elements from the original array. I'm looking for an output like : 
**6(index of 2), 4(index of 3), 3(index of 4), 2(index of 7), 5(index of 8), 1(index of 10)**

Answer (score 50):

The function you're looking for is `order`:

```
> x
[1] 10  7  4  3  8  2
> order(x)
[1] 6 4 3 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 28):

`sort` has `index.return` argument, which by default is `FALSE`

```
x <- c(10,7,4,3,8,2)
sort(x, index.return=TRUE) #returns a list with `sorted values` 
#and `$ix` as index.
#$x
#[1]  2  3  4  7  8 10

#$ix
#[1] 6 4 3 2 5 1
```

You can extract the `index` by

```
sort(x, index.return=TRUE)$ix
#[1] 6 4 3 2 5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get the same array indices returned by `which`, you should use `arrayInd` function:

```
array = matrix(rnorm(36),nrow=6)
sortIndex = sort(array, index.return=TRUE)$ix
array_indices = arrayInd(sortIndex,dim(array),dimnames(array),useNames = TRUE)
```